# CakePHP 2 Basic Auth Authentication

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, http-authentication, cakephp-2.2

I am moving from CakePHP 1.3 to CakePHP 2.2.2 and want to use Basic Http authentication for a simple admin area. I am just not able to make it work and I am thinking that I understood something wrong in the documentation.

From the documentation I understood I have to do something like

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
      'authenticate' => array(
        'Basic'
      ),
      'authError' => 'You may not access this area.',
      'authorize' => array('Controller')
    )
  );
```

I understand that further I need to extend the BaseAuthenticate Component to return valid user date but even with the above configuration I would expect that the browser's Http Access Dialog would open up in a popup window. But nothing like this happens, instead I am redirected to /users/login which does not exist. Why do I need a login view for Http Access? I am confused.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the `Auth` component to your controller (or to the `AppController`)

```
class ThingsController extends AppController {  
    var $components = array('Auth');
}
```

CakePHP requires a **login action**, so even if you use Basic authentication, where the HTTP agent is responsible for the UI to collect authentication details, you need to designate an action in some controller which will handle the login (in the Basic case, it will send the `WWW-Authenticate: Basic` header if the user is not authenticated yet).

You can set the `AuthCompoment`'s `$loginAction`, but this defaults (and is advisable not to break conventions) to the `login` method in the `UsersController`. So, first create an empty template at `View/Users/login.ctp`, then add the following to your `UsersController`

```
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array('Basic')
        )
    );

    public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Not able to login');
        }
    }

    public function logout() {
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }

}
```